# Initializing multiple data frames

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have made multiple lists by using split:

```
mylists <- split (df, interaction(df$age, df$nation)
```

From it, we got 1000 lists, `mylists[[1]]`, `mylists[[2]]`, ... `mylists[[1000]]`

How can we make (corresponding) 1000 data frames which hold the information of 1000 lists from it? (As when I try to do it by converting list into data frame in a loop, it does not work as we need to initialize a vector of 1000 data frames.)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question fully, I don't see that you need to do anything at all since what's in your list are *already* dataframes. Let's do a little demonstration using the `iris` dataframe that we'll modify slightly.

```
iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species2 <- rev(iris2$Species)
mylists <- split(iris2, interaction(iris2$Species, iris2$Species2))

length(mylists)

# [1] 9

sapply(mylists, class)

#     setosa.setosa     versicolor.setosa      virginica.setosa 
#      "data.frame"          "data.frame"          "data.frame" 
# setosa.versicolor versicolor.versicolor  virginica.versicolor 
#      "data.frame"          "data.frame"          "data.frame" 
#  setosa.virginica  versicolor.virginica   virginica.virginica 
#      "data.frame"          "data.frame"          "data.frame"
```

You can extract those dataframes either from their number or from their names:

```
head(mylists[[3]])

#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species Species2
# 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica   setosa
# 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica   setosa
# 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica   setosa
# 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica   setosa
# 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica   setosa
# 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica   setosa

names(mylists)

# [1] "setosa.setosa"         "versicolor.setosa"     "virginica.setosa"     
# [4] "setosa.versicolor"     "versicolor.versicolor" "virginica.versicolor" 
# [7] "setosa.virginica"      "versicolor.virginica"  "virginica.virginica"  

head(mylists[["virginica.setosa"]])

#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species Species2
# 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica   setosa
# 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica   setosa
# 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica   setosa
# 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica   setosa
# 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica   setosa
# 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica   setosa
```

Comment: we have to split based on two features.... Can you take some other examples  .<br/>.mylists <- split (df, interaction(df$age, rev(df$age), df$nation, rev(df$age))

Comment: What I suppose it would do is make more complex names for each item... I'm not sure what's your next step in all of this... Maybe you want to remove empty datasets...?

Comment: Iris is not the right example as it has no two features(categorical). Can you give another example where I can split on two features

Comment: Well I added a second factor for that reason... what else do you need? Check what `names(mylists)` gives you, from there you'll know how to access your df's by name.